# How to cache a questionnaire?

Tags: http, caching, symfony, varnish

**The situation:**

I've got a questionnaire on my website that my users fill in. I show one question per page. (This is a hard requirement.) So my user GETs a question, POSTs an answer and then is redirected to the next question.

**The challenge:**

Since the questions is always the same I want to cache those in a reverse proxy cache. The problem is RFC2616 that states:

> **RFC2616 13.10 Invalidation After Updates or Deletions**
>
> The effect of certain methods performed on a resource at the origin server might cause one or more existing cache entries to become non-transparently invalid. That is, although they might continue to be "fresh", they do not accurately reflect what the origin server would    return for a new request on that resource.

The consequence of this is after each POST and also POST>REDIRECT will the cached copy be marked as stale. So my questions is in the cache but is never reused.

I do see the benefits of this in general but in my case it makes my questions uncachable.

**The question:**

I can't be the first one with this problem. I'm looking for a solution that caches the GET responses for the question resource.

Comment: I don't see why there would be much trouble caching the GETs, unless you POST to the very same url making the cache confused as to what is cachable. So, differents URLs for the POST & GET, and most stuff will work out-of-the-box.

Comment: You can't do that because of RFC2616 13.10... that's the problem...

The solution here is to ignore RFC2616 13.10. I guess you can't follow every standard.